# Como atualizar indexes de uma listagem dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html

Eu tenho uma tabela aonde eu listo a quantidade de itens de um pedido. E em cada linha eu tenho um número de `01` a `15` sequencial onde identifica a quantidade de itens.

O problema é que quando eu excluo um item, o interessante era que os números que identifica cada linha atualiza-se automaticamente e ficassem aleatórios. Entenderam? 
Obs: A lista é feita em tabela.

```
<table id="table_itens" class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="exc_01">
          <td>01</td><!-- Estes números que eu quero atualizar dinamicamente -->
      </tr>
      <tr id="exc_02">
          <td>02</td><!-- Estes números que eu quero atualizar dinamicamente -->
      </tr>
      <tr id="exc_03">
          <td>03</td><!-- Estes números que eu quero atualizar dinamicamente -->
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Código JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function adicionaItemPedido(){ 

  var contador = (cont < 10) ? '0'+ cont++ : cont++;

  $("#table_itens").append(
     '<tr id="exc_'+ contador +'">\n\
         <td><b>'+ contador +'</b></td>\n\
            <td>'+ referencia_estofado[0] +'</td>\n\
               <td><input type="hidden" class="id_est_revest_aux" value="'+ $("#revestimento_aux").val() +'" />'+ revestimento[0] +'</td>\n\
               <td><input type="hidden" class="id_padrao_aux" value="'+ $("#cod_padrao option:selected").val() +'" />'+ $("#cod_padrao option:selected").text() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ (($("#revestimento_aux_2").val() === 'undefined') ? "-" : $("#revestimento_aux_2").val()) +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ (($("#cod_padrao_2").val() === 'undefined')       ? "-" : $("#cod_padrao_2").val()) +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ referencia_estofado[1] +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#quantidade").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#valor_unitario").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#desconto_acrescimo").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#valor_total").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnRemover"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></i> Remover</button></td>\n\
     </tr>'); 
}   
</script>
```

Comment: Como assim "ficassem aleatórios"? Se você tinha `1, 2, 3, 4` e removeu o `2`, é pra ficar `1, 2, 3` (o `3` virar `2` e o `4` virar `3`) ou é outra coisa?

Comment: Olá @mgibsonbr é exatamente isso. Vc tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Eu *evito* fazer isso, preferindo marcar os itens excluídos com um `<del></del>` (i.e. mostrando-os cortados) e mantendo a numeração, para simplificar. Mas se é isso mesmo que você quer, sei fazer sim, só um momento...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, ao adicionar um elemento verifique quantos já estão lá:

```
function adicionaItemPedido(){ 
  cont = $("#table_itens tr").length + 1;
  ...
```

Então, quando o usuário clicar em um botão remover, atualize toda linha posterior à linha sendo removida, e ao final remova a própria linha:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnRemover", function() {
  var linha = $(this).closest("tr"); // Acha a linha a ser removida

  // Recupera seu número (para atualizar os demais itens)
  var numero = parseInt(linha.attr("id").split("_")[1], 10);

  // Para cada irmão depois dessa linha...
  linha.nextAll().each(function() {
    // ...atualiza o id
    this.id = "exc_" + (numero < 10 ? "0" + numero : numero);
    // ...e o número exibido na tela
    $(this).find("td:eq(0) b").text(numero < 10 ? "0" + numero : numero);
    numero++;
  });

  linha.remove(); // remove a linha
});
```

(note que eu usei o [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) de modo que o código do botão remover se aplique a todos os botões com essa classe, atuais ou futuros. Se você estiver usando uma versão do jQuery anterior à 1.7, terá de substituí-los por `live`, `delegate` ou outra coisa.)

Exemplo completo:

```js
var referencia_estofado = [1,2];
var revestimento = [1];

function adicionaItemPedido(){ 
  cont = $("#table_itens tr").length + 1;

  var contador = (cont < 10) ? '0'+ cont++ : cont++;

  $("#table_itens").append(
     '<tr id="exc_'+ contador +'">\n\
         <td><b>'+ contador +'</b></td>\n\
            <td>'+ referencia_estofado[0] +'</td>\n\
               <td><input type="hidden" class="id_est_revest_aux" value="'+ $("#revestimento_aux").val() +'" />'+ revestimento[0] +'</td>\n\
               <td><input type="hidden" class="id_padrao_aux" value="'+ $("#cod_padrao option:selected").val() +'" />'+ $("#cod_padrao option:selected").text() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ (($("#revestimento_aux_2").val() === 'undefined') ? "-" : $("#revestimento_aux_2").val()) +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ (($("#cod_padrao_2").val() === 'undefined')       ? "-" : $("#cod_padrao_2").val()) +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ referencia_estofado[1] +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#quantidade").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#valor_unitario").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#desconto_acrescimo").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td>'+ $("#valor_total").val() +'</td>\n\
               <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnRemover"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ></i> Remover</button></td>\n\
     </tr>'); 
}   

$(document).on("click", ".btnRemover", function() {
  var linha = $(this).closest("tr"); // Acha a linha a ser removida
  
  // Recupera seu número (para atualizar os demais itens)
  var numero = parseInt(linha.attr("id").split("_")[1], 10);
  
  // Para cada irmão depois dessa linha...
  linha.nextAll().each(function() {
    // ...atualiza o id
    this.id = "exc_" + (numero < 10 ? "0" + numero : numero);
    // ...e o número exibido na tela
    $(this).find("td:eq(0) b").text(numero < 10 ? "0" + numero : numero);
    numero++;
  });

  linha.remove(); // remove a linha
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table_itens" class="table table-striped">
   <thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr id="exc_01">
          <td>01</td><!-- Estes números que eu quero atualizar dinamicamente -->
      </tr>
      <tr id="exc_02">
          <td>02</td><!-- Estes números que eu quero atualizar dinamicamente -->
      </tr>
      <tr id="exc_03">
          <td>03</td><!-- Estes números que eu quero atualizar dinamicamente -->
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
<button onclick="adicionaItemPedido()">Adicionar</button>
```

P.S. Em termos de Experiência do Usuário (UX), eu recomendaria tomar cuidado com alguns detalhes:

1. Se o usuário clicar no botão remover duas vezes por acidente, ele pode acabar removendo duas linhas... Talvez fosse interessante bloquear o uso do botão remover por um segundo que seja (acompanhado de uma indicação visual, é claro), para evitar essa possibilidade.
2. Se duas linhas forem iguais ou muito parecidas, o usuário pode achar que a remoção não funcionou (pois o índice se mantém constante após a atualização) e clicar em remover de novo, frustrando-se por perder um item que ainda queria.

   Por essa razão, eu pessoalmente costumo não remover o item de fato mas simplesmente *marcá-lo como removido*. Isso é feito envolvendo o elemento em uma tag `<del>` (<del>exemplo</del>) ou talvez via CSS (`text-decoration:line-through;`). Dessa forma, se o usuário se arrepender ele ainda pode restaurá-lo, pelo menos enquanto ele ainda não tiver submetido os dados ao servidor.

Comment: Muito obrigado funcionou perfeitamente agradeço. vlws!

Comment: Eu ia indicar [essa página no FAQ](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta), mas vejo que você já descobriu sozinho hehe :)

Comment: Neh! hahahahaha